# connected to ethernet and wifi, "route" browser's connection to wifi only

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, browser, route

Sometimes, in my company, I have to work with a different network (through ethernet) that has no internet. On the other hand, I do have access to out Wifi, which has internet. Since I have to spend a long time working in that network, I would like to find a way to use my Wifi's network to access the internet. I am open to different solutions, I thought of two that may be possible (?)

1. Setting a *browser* to "route" its access to internet through wifi only.
2. Using only *rdesktop* (the application where I have to work when connected) with the ethernet network, having everything else through wifi.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this or a better solution?

Comment: Which OS? Do you use NetworkManager?

Comment: @xx4h I am using elementaryOS (Ubuntu) and I never used NetworkManager. I have read around internet about routing (with `route` and `ip`) based on the ips, but as I said (and I know that maybe I am making it more complicated) I do not have to always work like this. When I have to connect to that network I plug a different ethernet cable. So... maybe too complicated?